# Debugging unserialize errors

Tags: multisite, errors, debug

`NOTICE: wp-includes/functions.php:232 - unserialize()`

I get this error of varying lengths on the admin pages of several of the sub-blogs of my multisite instance.  It doesn't happen on all the blogs, and doesn't immediately seem to be tied to a specific plugin.  Does any know an efficient way to debug these messages (short of manually running the 131 queries and counting the data) or a good way to rebuild serialized data in the database?